# After selecting from a MySQL table, another INSERT INTO will always fail

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My website is trying to realize a login, where you have to ask another person to accept yout to the homepage. The relevant part of the script looks like this

```
require_once("konfiguration.php");
                    $abfrage = "SELECT nick FROM login";
                    $db_erg = mysqli_query($db_link, $abfrage);
                    $counter = 0;
                    $cache = array();

                    while($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array($db_erg, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                        $cache[$counter]['nick'] = $zeile['nick'];
                        $counter++;
                    }
                    $fail = true;
                    $nope = "Der Nick-Name existiert nicht";
                    for($i = 0 ; $i <= $counter ; $i++) {
                        if($cache[$i]['nick'] == $asknick) {
                            $fail = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!$fail) {
                        require_once("konfiguration.php");
                        $eintrag = "INSERT INTO  `homepage`.`request` (from, to, accepted, id) VALUES ('".$benutzername."', '".$asknick."', '0', '')";
                        $eintragen = mysqli_query($db_link, $eintrag);
                        if(!$eintragen) {
                            die("Es gab einen unerwarteten Fehler beim registrieren..");
                        }

                        $eintrag2 = "INSERT INTO  `homepage`.`login` (id, nutzername, passwort, loginhash, nick, email) VALUES ('', '".$benutzername."', '".md5($password)."', '".$hashwert."', '".$nickname."', '".$email."')";
                        $eintragen2 = mysqli_query($db_link, $eintrag2);
                        if(!$eintragen2) {
                            die("Es gab einen unwerarteten Fehler beim registrieren..");
                        }
                        session_start();
                        setcookie("username", $benutzername);
                        ?>
```

After you insert a nickname of a person, that shall accept you, i select all nicknames from a database where all people are already registered and accepted. If the nickname exists, i tried to write into another database (as you can see in $eintrag) who wants to be accepted, who shall accept him, is he already accepted. The problem is, that everytime, i try it, it fails ($eintragen = false). I just can't see the error.
Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Please provide a table structure. Maybe you have some database limitations.

Comment: Table login:                                                                                            id | username | password | loginhash | nick | email | activ                   Table request:                                           from | to | accepted | id

Comment: Sorry. i can't force a linebreak -.-

Comment: well, as i can see, usually `id` fields are autoincrement. I dont know if its your case, so check it and if its true, dont provide empty string as `id`.

Comment: I tried it with every possible combination, and i still get an error, if i trie to connect

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Apparently you are not allowed to us "from" and "to", not even in a table structur. I changed "from" and "to" in the MySQL-Table to "person1" and "person2", adjusted the code and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many more reserved words, this is why I always prefer using prefixes on tables and columns. Such as instead of table "login" name it "t_login", instead of string column "from" use "s_from". This way your code is much more easy to read and you will evade conflicts with reserved words.

Comment: if you properly escape them, then you don't need to prefix. I don't recommend prefixing.